# Who was the first Jew who was called with two names?

Tags: history, names

**Who was the first Jew who was called with two names?**

I'm not asking "Who was the fist Jew who had two names?" like Yaakov [Israel] or Benyamin [Ben-Oni] had, I'm asking who was the first Jew who got "Yossef-Dov" or "Avraham-Yitzhak" type of naming - both names are called at once.

Also, I'm not looking for:

Acronyms ("Rashi")
Titles ("*Hazaken*","*Hakadosh*")
Name made of two words that serve one meaning ("Shar-Yashuv", "Oved-Edom")
Nicknames ("The Staipller")
Two names with the same meaning ("Dov Ber", "Maher Shalal - Chash Bazz")

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.7.3?lang=bi  https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.7.14?lang=bi https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.8.3?lang=bi https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.9.5?lang=bi

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9987/170

Comment: Why do you reject Dov Ber but allow Menachem Mendel?

Comment: Shear Yashuv has a tipcha on Shear

Comment: *Tuval Kayin*! Genesis 4:22 - https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.4.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he

Comment: In the modern period, you have the Maharsha, Rabbi Shmuel Eliezer, born 1555 in Krakow

Answer (score 4):

First one who comes to mind is Obed-Edom, [Divrei Hayamim 15:24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Chronicles.15.24?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)

> וּשְׁבַנְיָ֡הוּ וְיֽוֹשָׁפָ֡ט וּנְתַנְאֵ֡ל וַעֲמָשַׂ֡י וּ֠זְכַרְיָהוּ וּבְנָיָ֤הוּ וֶֽאֱלִיעֶ֙זֶר֙ הַכֹּ֣הֲנִ֔ים מחצצרים [מַחְצְרִים֙] בַּחֲצֹ֣צְר֔וֹת לִפְנֵ֖י אֲר֣וֹן הָֽאֱלֹהִ֑ים וְעֹבֵ֤ד אֱדֹם֙ וִֽיחִיָּ֔ה שֹׁעֲרִ֖ים לָאָרֽוֹן׃
>
> Shebaniah, Joshaphat, Nethanel, Amasai, Zechariah, Benaiah, and Eliezer the priests sounded the trumpets before the Ark of God, and Obed-edom and Jehiah were gatekeepers for the Ark.

Comment: I saw in a sefer about this question that there is a rishon quoted in Tosafos named Yaakov Yisroel or Yisroel Yaakov.

Comment: @Meuchedet See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9998/3

Comment: Was this not explicitly excited in the question post?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות that was an edit after this answer was posted. There were some deleted comments here debating if this is a two-word name like Shar-Yashuv, or if it is two separate names like Yaakov Yosef. Either way I don't think its what the OP wanted since its an anomaly from ancient times, and not an early instance of the modern two-name practice we recognize.

Comment: Tuval Kayin! Genesis 4:22 - sefaria.org.il/Genesis.4.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he

Comment: @DannySchoemann Tuval Kayin wasn't Jewish